# Merging multiple images next to each other in PHP

Tags: php, image, png

I've been looking around for some helpful tips on working with images in PHP since i'm fairly new to it.

I have a folder of 7 images all the same size; 35 x 75. I want to randomly select 6 of them and put them next to each other on the x axis, as one image.

Here is what I came up with but I'm not sure what's wrong at the moment. I've worked with PHP before but not with any of the image functions.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');

$numbers = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9);

$random1 = rand(0, 6);
$random2 = rand(0, 6);
$random3 = rand(0, 6);
$random4 = rand(0, 6);
$random5 = rand(0, 6);
$random6 = rand(0, 6);

$newid = array($numbers[$random1], $numbers[$random2], $numbers[$random3], $numbers[$random4], $numbers[$random5], $numbers[$random6]);

$count = 0;
foreach($newid as $imageSrc) {
    $count++;
    $image = imagecreatefrompng("numbers/" . $imageSrc . ".png");
    imagecopymerge($dest, $image, (35*$count), 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image), 100);
    imagepng($dest);
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `imagepng` outside of loop:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');

$numbers = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9);

shuffle($numbers);
$newid=array_slice($numbers,0,6);

$count = 0;
$dest=imagecreatetruecolor(35*6,75);
foreach($newid as $imageSrc) {

    $image = imagecreatefrompng("numbers/" . $imageSrc . ".png");
    imagecopymerge($dest, $image, (35*$count), 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image), 100);
    $count++;
}
imagepng($dest);

?>
```

Comment: I'm getting "imagecopymerge() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given". Something to do with the $dest I think...

Comment: Nearly there, the first image is appearing black for some reason, the rest is working though. Appreciate the help!

Comment: edited - move `$count++` after putting image so the first position is 0 not 35

Comment: I know this isn't part of the question really, but when I try to add a name to the image "imagepng($dest, "test.png");" it stops working! Thanks again.

Comment: because when you add this parameter it saves the image instead of outputing it. If you want to save it as test.png and it doesn't work - check directory permissions